# Bound the error of numerical ODE simulation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, error-propagation

Let's assume, I have an autonomous ODE of the form
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\cdot f_i(y)
$$
which I want to solve numerically in $t\in[0, t_{end}]$ with some initial condition $y(0)=y_0$.
I already know, that the system is well behaved (bounded, non-stiff, stable, etc) and so can use straight-forward ODE45-like solvers and not care about time-discretization errors.

My problem is, that $f(y)$ is not correct but only an approximation, as I have to approximate the values for $\alpha_i$ in the ODE.
So the "real solution" denoted by $\tilde{y}$ is given by with
$$\frac{d\tilde{y}}{dt} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i+\epsilon_i)\cdot f_i(\tilde{y})$$ and $\tilde{y}(0) = y_0$.

Can I give a bound on $|\tilde{y}(t_{end})-y(t_{end})|$ depending on the magnitude of $\epsilon_i$?

I already tried reusing bounds derived for errors caused by time-steps but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe you could use Bellman Gronwall to bound the solution of the error $\tilde{y}-y = \sum_i \alpha_i (f_i(\tilde{y})-f_i(y)) + \sum_i \epsilon_i f_i(\tilde{y})$?

Comment: I read about Bellman-Gronwall Lemma and it seems suitable. But I don't arrive at the same result as you do. (especially with the norms, the Lipschitz-constant and the bounding-function). But I will continue on that route.